# Plot NMSE performance under different SNR values

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, conv-neural-network

I don't know how to plot the NMSE performance of a CNN at different SNR values.

I have found the CNN in the paper "Distributed Machine Learning Based Downlink Channel Estimation for RIS Assisted Wireless Communications" doi: https://10.1109/TCOMM.2022.3175175, the simulation codes is available on the paper.
This is the Denoising CNN for channel estimation:

```
def DeCNN(block, depth, channels, filters = 64):

    input = Input(shape=(None, None, channels))
    input_ = input
    x = input_

    kernel_size = 3

    while block:
        input_ = x
        x = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same',
                   kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', use_bias=False, data_format='channels_last')(input_)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        # for depth-2:Conv+BN+Relu
        for _ in range(depth-2):
            x = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same',
                       kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', use_bias=False, data_format='channels_last')(input_)
            x = BatchNormalization(axis=3, momentum=0.85, epsilon=0.0001)(x)  
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = Conv2D(filters=channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same',
                   kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', use_bias=False, data_format='channels_last')(x)
        x = Subtract()([input_, x])  # input-noise
        block -= 1

    model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = x)
    return model
```

This is the loss function:

```
def NMSE_RIS(y_true, y_pred):     
    r_true = y_true[:,:,:,0]      
    i_true = y_true[:,:,:,1]      
    r_pred = y_pred[:,:,:,0]
    i_pred = y_pred[:,:,:,1]
    mse_r_sum = K.sum(K.sum(K.square(r_pred - r_true), -1), -1)  
    r_sum = K.sum(K.sum(K.square(r_true), -1), -1)
    mse_i_sum = K.sum(K.sum(K.square(i_pred - i_true), -1), -1)
    i_sum = K.sum(K.sum(K.square(i_true), -1), -1)
    num = mse_r_sum + mse_i_sum         
    den = r_sum + i_sum                 
    return num/den
```

The rest of the code is here: http://oa.ee.tsinghua.edu.cn/dailinglong/publications/publications.html
At the end of the paper they do NMSE performance comparison at different snr, something like that: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Joizo.png)
My question is: How they do this?
I generate train set and test set with different SNR, train and evaluate the model with this different set and defined a method to save average NMSE in a specific SNR:

```
def save_NMSE(self, SNRdB):
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(SNRdB, np.mean(self.losses['epoch']), 'bo', label='NMSE')
        plt.title('NMSE performance')
        plt.xlabel('SNRdB')
        plt.ylabel('NMSE')
        plt.legend(loc="upper right")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.savefig('NMSE_'+ str(SNRdB) +'dB_curve.png')
```

But this generate a png file with one point at every SNR (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnVY0.png).
What I want is a plot with all point like the one above.